# Reactivity comparison between benzaldehyde and acetaldehyde

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds, stability, reactivity

One of my teacher says that $\ce{Ph-CHO}$ is more reactive than $\ce{CH3-CHO}$ in performing nucleophillic addition reaction because $\ce{—Ph}$ is planar and thus offers less steric hindrance as compared to $\ce{—CH3}$ which is tetrahedral.

My other teacher gives the reason that the partial positive charge developed on the carbonyl carbon is resonance stabilised in $\ce{Ph-CHO}$ which makes the carbonyl carbon more prone to nucleophillic attacks.

What I think is that $\ce{—Ph}$ has its −*I* effect which deprives the carbonyl carbon of some amount of its electron density and thus makes it more prone to nucleophillic attacks.

I want to know which reason is more correct in explaining the reactivity of  benzaldehyde over acetaldehyde or if there is some other reason please specify.
The main thing I want to know by this is that whether planar substitutents offer less steric resistance than tetrahedral or not, and whether a partial charge on carbon can be stabilised by resonance or not.

Comment: The first reasoning reminded me of the prank often performed on first-graders. Shall one get a stuck glass joint during a lab practicum, the person is often told to soak the glassware in benzene, and here comes the sanity check. A first-grader ask why, and receives an explanation that planar benzene rings can easier penetrate the space between glass surfaces and wedge a joint at once. Student accepting such explanation usually don't do well during the first exam session.

Comment: $\ce{-CH3}$ has an [A-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_value) of 1.7 whereas $\ce{-Ph}$ has an A-value of 3. I'm also inclined to mark this as a duplicate of [This answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/93719/reactivity-of-benzaldehyde-between-aldehydes)

Comment: Be sure to check for resonances _before inductives_. Also, I'm not able to get the sense of _"partial carbocation"_?

Comment: @RahulVerma ; by partial carbocation I am trying to indicate the partial +ve charge on the carbonyl carbon

Comment: I'm confused in your initial lines where you write, _"substitution nucleophillic addition elimination"_. I can't see which one are you asking?

Comment: @RahulVerma; actually I’m talking about the attack of Nucleophile on the carbonyl carbon.

Comment: If you're having 12th NCERT Chemistry part 2, then go to pg 358. Read it carefully, and you'll see why your teachers are _wrong_ (really sorry for saying so)

Comment: I suspect that your second teacher has the right idea. Resonance stabilization renders benzaldehyde less susceptible to nucleophilic attack at the carbonyl group than acetaldehyde. Which brings up an additional question. How would you prove it?

Comment: @andselisk Do you mean first-year college students or first grade elementary students (6 year olds)? ;-)

Comment: @KarstenTheis Oops, I mean university students in their first year. Sorry for the lousy (plain wrong) choice of terminology, I still sometimes fail to figure out a proper term from the mishmash of education systems.